# how to Search Table Column stored CSV

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I Have Columns to store tags like this "tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4" I wan to be able to search the tag using like key word Resources.tags
this is my sql Query result is 0

```
Select Resources.tags from Resources where Resources.tags  like '% tags2 %'
```

Comment: Why are you storing tags as a comma separated list?  Please normalize your table structure.

Comment: `WHERE ',' + tags + ',' LIKE '%,' + @tag + ',%';`

Comment: Agree with @bluefeet. You should have a Tags table, so you only ever store the string "Tag1" once, then a relational table that maps resources to tags.

Comment: I agree  with you but we aren't doing tags cloud we just want to store keyword.

Comment: Not sure why you need to have a tag cloud to justify storing this data more efficiently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do your tags have spaces or just commas?  Your syntax was fine except that it was looking for ' tags2 ' instead of 'tags2':

```
SELECT Resources.tags 
FROM Resources 
WHERE Resources.tags  LIKE '%tags2%'
```

Bad practice in general, but this should work.

To add some protection against picking up unwanted values you could force comma positions:

```
SELECT Resources.tags 
FROM Resources 
WHERE Resources.tags  LIKE '%,tags2'
   OR Resources.tags  LIKE 'tags2,%'
   OR Resources.tags  LIKE '%,tags2,%'
```

Remember that best practice is to not keep multiple values in the same field.

Comment: *‘… but this should work.’* – Unless it catches a tag like `xtags22`.